# Combining two queries into one

Tags: php, mysql

I have two type of message, one is private message and another is credit message are inserting into two different table. Now I'm trying to fetch the data.

```
SELECT * ,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM votes 
           WHERE message_id = m.message_id
             AND vote_type = 'like') AS likes,
          (SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM votes
           WHERE message_id = m.message_id 
           AND vote_type = 'dislike') AS dislikes 
FROM messages m
WHERE 1 #and hidden is null
  and recipient_id = 1
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

and

```
SELECT * ,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM votes 
           WHERE message_id = m.message_id
             AND vote_type = 'like') AS likes,
          (SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM votes
           WHERE message_id = m.message_id  
             AND vote_type = 'dislike') AS dislikes 
FROM private_messages m 
WHERE 1 #and hidden is null 
  and recipient_id = 1 
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Now want to merge them into one query one extra parameter will show its private message or credit message.

Comment: Please learn to format your code after 66 posts of yours.

Comment: Please show us your attempt to merge the queries. Explain what results you wish to achieve and how your attempt failed to provide those results.

Comment: SELECT * ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE message_id = m.message_id AND vote_type = 'like') AS likes,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE message_id = m.message_id AND vote_type = 'dislike') AS dislikes FROM messages m WHERE 1 #and hidden is nulland recipient_id = 1 ORDER BY datetime DESC UNION ALL SELECT * ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE message_id = m.message_id AND vote_type = 'like') AS likes,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE message_id = m.message_id AND vote_type = 'dislike') AS dislikes FROM messages m WHERE 1 #and hidden is nulland recipient_id = 1 ORDER BY datetime DESC

Comment: 40 questions later and you still can't find the edit button

Comment: But unable to mark first query as normal message and second one as importent message. and 4 downvote for it..

Comment: Yes, if you wouldn't mind editing questions rather than adding large code chunks in comments, that helps future readers see the question much more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the existing queries do what you want/need, `UNION` will make it pretty simple to combine them, something like;

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT is_private 0, <field1>,<field2>,<field3>, ... ,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
               FROM votes 
               WHERE message_id = m.message_id
                 AND vote_type = 'like') AS likes,
              (SELECT COUNT(*) 
               FROM votes
               WHERE message_id = m.message_id 
               AND vote_type = 'dislike') AS dislikes 
    FROM messages m
    WHERE 1 #and hidden is null
      and recipient_id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, <field1>, <field2>, <field3>, ... ,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
               FROM votes 
               WHERE message_id = m.message_id
                 AND vote_type = 'like') AS likes,
              (SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM votes
               WHERE message_id = m.message_id  
                 AND vote_type = 'dislike') AS dislikes 
    FROM private_messages m 
    WHERE 1 #and hidden is null 
      and recipient_id = 1 
)
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Note that you need to select the same number/order of columns from both queries for the union to work. `SELECT *` makes it hard to verify if/that that is the case. If

Comment: Plz check my query, i m doing that, but unable to mark first query as impotent and second as normal. This is required when i am creating json for the mobile app to distinguish between the two type of messages

Comment: @Shyantanu Did you try the query? It marks private messages as private.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION to combine mysql query:

SELECT id FROM table_user
UNION
SELECT COUNT(vote) FROM table_vote

You can use multiple UNION query by UNION.

Like,

Query 1

UNION

Query 2

UNION

.....
.....
.....

Query n

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is a much simpler way to express the logic:

```
select m.*, v.likes, v.dislikes
from (select v.message_id, sum(vote_type = 'like') AS likes, sum(vote_type = 'dislike') AS dislikes
      from votes v
      group by v.message_id
     ) v join
     (select m.*, 'Message' as which
      from messages
      union all
      select pm.*, 'PrivateMessage' as which
      from private_messages pm
     ) m
     on v.message_id = m.message_id;
```